# What do when your flowering plants shoots its growth?

Tags: diagnosis

I live in south India. Right now the it's summer here  transitioning to occasional rainfall. So the temperature is much controlled than previous week.

Problem : Over the years I have noticed, my flowering plants(ex:Geranium) tend to grow very tall without many leaves at the bottom and few leaves crowded at the top. And  these do not flower also. Eventually they break in the off season like winter and would not grow back.

1. Why does this happen?
2. What should I do with the plants which are growing as tall as 2 ft?
3. Apart from feeding nitrogen fertilizer, am I missing anything?

Comment: When you say 'geranium', do you mean Pelargonium, or actual Geranium spp?  Are these plants growing in shade, and are they crowded together?  A photo or two would be helpful if you can add a couple.

Comment: I am unsure of the plant name. It is sort of under shade but receives 3-4 hours of good sunlight in the morning. Will add a picture once I reach home. 

I did prune them a bit since they were growing like a stick